# how to point out the index location of all duplicate characters in a string

Tags: java

is there a way to check how many duplicate char in a string and point out its index location? i'm using indexOf() method. however it will only return the first result. and the other remaining same letter will not be returned. also i want to know if its possible to know its index location of all duplicate letters.

here is the fragment of the code that i'm currently using.

```
 String word = "RASPBERRY";
 char letter = 'R';
 int indx = 0;

 indx = word.indexOf(letter);
```

Comment: `indexOf` can take a second parameter, the index to begin searching from.  So to find the *next* index of a character after `indx`, you would use `word.indexOf(letter, indx)`.

Comment: @Vulcan, i appreciate your way of guiding towards an answer. upvote for you.

Comment: thanks for the answer sir Vulcan unfortunately i am having a problem regarding the code. will it be possible to give me some example on it. like the code that i posted. if you wouldn't mind thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the indexof only returns the first matched position from the starting of specific position, for your case,  maybe, a loop can find all positions that this char appears in this string.

```
String word = "RASPBERRY";
char letter = 'R';
int start = word.indexOf(letter);

while(start != -1) {
     System.out.println("Found R in: " + start);
     start = word.indexOf(letter, ++start);
}
```

Comment: You should test code before placing it in an answer.  This code loops infinitely.

Answer (score 2):

```
String word = "RASPBERRY";
char letter = 'R';
int indx = word.indexOf(letter);

while (indx != -1) {
   System.out.println("Index at " + indx);
   indx = word.indexOf(letter, indx + 1);
}
```